# How to allocate memory dynamically when array is declared with 1 element

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider a structure like following:

`typedef struct {
  int arrCount;
  int arr[1];
} SampleStruct, *PSampleStruct;`

I know that `arr` is an int array that needs a dynamic memory allocation at runtime and `arrCount` needs to hold the count of element. But when i try to allocate memory of, let say, 10 elements using malloc, compiler throws error that `arr must be a modifiable value`. I cant make how to allocate memory to such array. Also, i have seen such examples in lot of Windows headers, but when i am trying to implement it,  i am totally lost.

Comment: instead of `int arr[1]`, use a `int *arr`. Then use malloc for arr

Comment: @Neo Using an int pointer/separate allocation for arr separates arr's lifetime from SampleStruct's, and in non-contiguous memory. The correct way is to allocate a pointer to a SampleStruct in a single malloc/alloca.

Comment: @Sanhadrin Your "correct" way is not strictly conforming C, because you end up accessing beyond sizeof the object. There's nothing "incorrect" about allocating separately. My answer provides both. (And does the single allocation "correctly", using offsetof.)

Comment: Thanks Jim. I was exactly referring to what you put below.

Comment: @Jim Balter Adhering rigidly to the standards when they themselves are poorly defined is completely unnecessary in many cases, this being one of them. The defined behavior of arrays and pointers makes this functionally correct and portable between every remotely used compiler on the face of the planet. The C standards committee saying "This works, but feels icky" and stating it's undefined behavior when the requirements of implementation makes it completely predictable means you would have to follow the standard slavishly to see any issue at all. Or - on which compiler does this not work?

Comment: A story about the Windows perspective on this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx

Comment: "Adhering rigidly to the standards when they themselves are poorly defined" -- The C standard is not "poorly defined", nor is adhering to it "unnecessary". Good luck with this form of argument in SO[c]. And in any case, again **I included the non-strictly conforming approach in my answer**.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That "story" is just about why one shouldn't do this sort of thing in a particularly stupid way that no one here is suggesting. It doesn't say why Microsoft *still hasn't written a C99 compiler*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `arr[1]` is *not* a pointer, `PSampleStruct` is. You'd do something like this:

`PSampleStruct ss10arr = malloc(sizeof (*ss10arr) + (sizeof(ss10arr->arr) * 9))` which will make `arr[0]` through `arr[9]` valid.

Note that this only works because `arr` is at the *end* of the structure.

Also note that some compiler options (like `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` with glibc and gcc) will complain if you try to access the subsequent elements because it will detect this as an overrun.

Comment: Although I got your point, but do you really think that `ss10arr` will be available to use in the right hand side of your code, while the variable is still not yet declared? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

When doing things this way, you typically don't allocate the array itself - you allocate the struct using malloc/alloca with a size of sizeof(SampleStruct) + the size of the allocation for arr[] - then arr[] is used to index into the allocated memory.

See [GCC's description of zero-length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) - it should be the same for an array of length 1, but is clearer in the intent of the memory usage.

Comment: Standard C has no zero-length arrays.

Comment: @Jim Balter I already stated this - the pattern is the exact same, minus taking one byte out of the malloc. It reinforces the earlier point and goes into more depth without having to re-cover it.

Comment: There is obviously no statement in your answer that C has no zero-length arrays. And "one *byte*" is quite wrong.

Comment: C99 allows zero length arrays, or "flexible" arrays; at least according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html though I'm not sure how well this is supported in VC, or C++/VC++. As a matter of habit, though, I try and keep to C89 compat

Comment: @mnunberg Flexible arrays are not zero-length arrays; as your citation says, they have *incomplete type*. But they are what should be used here (if the OP is using a C99 or later compiler, which Microsoft idiotically does not provide).

Comment: @Jim Balter - Yes, one byte is clearly wrong. Otherwise, I don't need to state that it's not ISO C, since the link does at the very beginning as it's a general description of the idiom, and if you don't read it the linked page, it's inconsequential.

Comment: My initial statement was correct and clarified an important point. All the follow-on discussion is what's inconsequential. Notably, answers that merely link to the relevant discussion are not considered a good thing at SO.

Comment: @Jim Balter My answer included a direct answer, so I wasn't "merely" linking to an answer. There's no problem with supplementary links on here. That's why the site supports hyperlinks, after all.

Comment: Again, your direct answer does not contain the important point I made.

Comment: @Jim Balter As I've already plainly said, my answer does not mention zero-length arrays, except for referencing separate supplementary material which directly describes how the idiom would be implemented in ISO C. Either you don't read the supplementary material and there's no issue, or you do and it's fully described. There is no "important point", so this has run its course.

Comment: It had run its course with my first comment, which needed no response. But your answer is wrong *unless* one uses zero-length arrays or flexible arrays, as it allocates more memory than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SampleStruct* pstruct = malloc(offsetof(SampleStruct, arr) + 10 * sizeof *pstruct->arr);
```

will allocate a pointer to a SampleStruct with 10 elements in `arr`. This will work on virtually every implementation but isn't strictly conforming. To be strictly conforming, change

```
int arr[1];
```

to

```
int* arr;
```

and do:

```
SampleStruct* pstruct = malloc(sizeof *pstruct);
pstruct->arr = malloc(10 * sizeof *pstruct->arr);
```

Edit: If you are using a C99 (or later) compiler (sadly, Microsoft's is not), you can use a *flexible array*. Change

```
int arr[1];
```

to

```
int arr[];
```

and then just do

```
SampleStruct* pstruct = malloc(sizeof *pstruct + 10 * sizeof *pstruct->arr);
```

Comment: Why is the `offsetof` required here?

Comment: @mnunberg offsetof properly excludes the size of arr[1]. It's simpler than `sizeof *pstruct - sizeof pstruct->arr`. (Or subtracting 1 from the count as in your answer, which contains syntax errors.)

Comment: I can see why the `offsetof` variant might better convey intent (though that's a matter of personal preference, I think). Is there any scenario where the `offsetof` variant will yield a _different_ result than `malloc(sizeof *foo + ((sizeof foo->arr) * count-1))` ?

Comment: @mnunberg Yes ... your expression is misparenthesized and yields the wrong value. Good programming practices are not just a matter of "personal preference". And if you fix that ... where someone changes it to arr[0] (gcc) or arr[] (C99) ... it then doesn't allocate enough memory, resulting in a subtle bug and UB. Using offsetof is an instance of the DRY principle ... it avoids knowing the dimension of arr, which is just an artifact.

Comment: At least one of the totally unwarranted downvotes is from Adam Palaniuk, who did it out of spite (see below).